# How do I list the user that started a service in freebsd

Tags: freebsd, service, truenas, ps, jail

Just a simple question, but I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find this.  I just need to know what user started a particular service.  In this case, I want to know what user runs the headphones service (headphones plugin in a FreeNAS jail).

I tried using `service headphones status` but that just gives me the PID (23069).  Is there a way to list the user using the PID instead?  I tried that as well using: `ps 23069` but that only gives the time running and path.

Comment: Tried ps aux ?.

Comment: That was it.  I knew it had to be something simple.  Thanks!

Comment: glad it helped :) will write as an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'ps aux' will do the tip to list all users process